# cannot connect Django app to Azure Database for MySQL with SSL certificate

Tags: mysql, django, azure, ssl

I want Enforce SSL connection with my Azure Database for MySQL. I followed all steps that are in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-configure-ssl#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20Azure%20portal%2C%20visit,connection%20setting%20for%20enhanced%20security.)

I connected public certificate in Workbench and everything seems to be ok:

[image]

I also checked status in mysql CLI and in SSL I see  `Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`.

but when I am trying to runserver I get error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (9002, 'SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.')
```

settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': config('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
    'OPTIONS': {
    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    'init_command': 'SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;'
                    'SET collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'
                    "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';"
                    "SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;"},
    'ssl': {
        'ca': '/var/www/html/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'
        }
}
```

}

I am guessing that something is wrong with ca path but I am not sure how should I change it.

I tried to connect to MySQL db with certificate using this command in mysql CLI (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035588/why-does-connection-to-my-mysql-server-in-azure-fail-if-my-app-does-not-have-ssl)) but it when I put server and username it gives me syntax error (I put exactly what is below).

```
mysql -h mydemoserver.mysql.database.azure.com -u Username@mydemoserver -p --ssl-ca=/opt/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem
```